# Creating a git repo for an existing set of files then pushing changes to it

Tags: git

This is my first time trying to use git to replace FTP for my website. I thought I had it working until I tried to push changes back to the site.

Here's what I've done:

On remote:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'initial commit'
```

Then on local I was able to get all the files from the server correctly using:

```
git clone ssh://user@mysite.com/path/
```

Which successfully cloned all the sites files to my local machine.

I made some changes locally, tested changes locally and I'm ready to upload them back to the website.

It's my understanding that this should work:

```
git push origin master
```

However, both that and a simple:

```
git push
```

both give the same error:

```
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
```

I played around with git checkout on the server, but this caused more issues as I had to checkout a different branch on the server, push to master, then checkout master again to see the changes! Not ideal as I want to be able to make changes to the website without running commands on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allowed to push into branches that are checked out on the other machine. Think of it this way: If somebody pushed into your currently checked out branch on your machine your editor would go crazy and you would lose the changes you made to the files before committing.

Hence, such a push-to-server-based approach is not possible.

```
you --push--> server                 # error
```

Instead, create a intermediary repository `repo` from wich the server will pull

```
you --push--> repo --pull--> server    # works
```

The intermediary `repo` must be created using `git init --bare`, making it a repo without a workspace and hence without a checked-out branch.

Comment: Also `repo` and `server` can both be on the same machine, the rest of what I explained still applies.

Comment: Does that mean that the pull command still has to be run on the server? I was hoping to give a few of my less technical users a .bat file they could run to upload all changes they've made and not require them to login via ssh. I know this is a different question but if the intermediary is on remote, can that be set to run an automatic pull on the 'live' files repo when something is committed to it?

Comment: Yes, you can do either a cronjob that periodically syncs the repos or set up a [hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) (look for `post-receive`)  in `repo` that uses `ssh` to connect to the server and run `git pull` there.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I need. The post-receive hook looks best for what I need as people can see their changes immediately.

Comment: You edited an Answer of mine from the Review Queue where the OP had made a "suggestion" to include their failed results in my Answer. Please don't do that. That type of edit should be rejected as Not a valid edit, or Vandalism

Answer (score 0):

In your deployment script, you'll want to log in to each production server via SSH and do a `git pull` from each repository.

```
ssh user@hostname cd /path/to/repo && git pull
```